# Did I correctly apply the factorisation theorem in this example?

Tags: probability, estimation, inference, estimators, sufficient-statistics

Suppose that we have a density $f(x,\theta)=c(\theta)\psi(x)\unicode{x1D7D9}(x \in]\theta,\theta+1[)$ and the random variable $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ are independently identically distributed from $f$, i.e.
$$X_i \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} f.$$
Find a sufficient statistic for this density.

**My attempt:** since the joint density $\Bbb L(\mathbf{X},\theta)=c(\theta)^n\Pi_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i) \unicode{x1D7D9}(\min ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n})\gt \theta)\unicode{x1D7D9}(\max ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n})<\theta)$ then we can write $\Bbb L(\mathbf{X},\theta)= g(T(x),\theta)h(x)$ with $h(\mathbf{X})=\Pi_{i=1}^n \psi(X_i)$ and $g(T(X),\theta)=c(\theta)^n\unicode{x1D7D9}(\min ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n})\gt \theta)\unicode{x1D7D9}(\max ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n})<\theta+1)$.

Therefore $T(X):=(\min ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n}),\, \max ((X_i)_{i=1}^{n}))$ is the sufficient statistic for this expression. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning seems right.

I think you assume $\mathbf{X}=(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, with $X_i$ independently identically distributed from $f$.

Then, you have correctly rewritten the likelihood $\mathbb{L}(\mathbf{X},\theta)$ as a function of the parameter $\theta$ that depends (up to a proportionality constant) on the sample $\mathbf{X}$ just via the statistic $T(\mathbf{X})=(\min (\mathbf{X}),\,  \max (\mathbf{X}))$.

Therefore, by definition of sufficient statistic, $T$ is a sufficient statistic and, intuitively, $T$ contains all the information you have on the parameter $\theta$ in terms of the likelihood.

Note that $T$ is not the only sufficient statistic. For instance, the sample $\mathbf{X}$ is always a sufficient statistic.