# If a statistic $T(X)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i$ is sufficient does that imply the mean is also sufficient?

Tags: mean, inference, sample, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

I've been working on some problems, the question asked me if the mean of a sample is a sufficient statistic for poisson distribution. I've already proved that $T(X)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic. Can I just conclude that the mean is also a sufficient statistic since we are just dividing by $n$?

And can we say the same about completeness? If $T(X)=\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete then the mean is also complete?

Comment: Yes by [factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem) and definition of complete statistic

Comment: Two statistics $S$ and $T$ are equivalent if there exists a one-to-one function $f$ such that $S = f(T)$. If two statistics are equivalent and one is a sufficient statistic, then so is the other.

Comment: @bdeonovic thank you for answering, can you check my other question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517792/did-i-correctly-apply-the-factorisation-theorem-in-this-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) intuitive definition:

> Roughly, given a set $\mathbf {X}$  of independent identically
> distributed data conditioned on an unknown parameter $\theta$ , a
> sufficient statistic is a function $T(\mathbf {X} )$ whose value
> contains all the information needed to compute any estimate of the
> parameter.

If $T(X)$ contains all the information, $T(X)/n$ contains all the information as well.

Comment: thank you for answering, can you check my other question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517792/did-i-correctly-apply-the-factorisation-theorem-in-this-example?

Answer (score 2):

$
f(X|mean=y,\theta)=f(X|\sum X_i =ny, \theta)=f(X| \sum X_i=ny) =f(X| mean =y)
$

So by definiton, yes